# Is there a set of heroes I shouldn't be using in ranked play?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some heroes just flat out out-class others according to some LoL players. I cannot easily source this as the sources are too many and opinions too varied. That being said, is there any way to clarify what heroes are definitly underclassed somehow? Is the concept even somewhat true? If so should these heroes be avoided in ranked play so as to minimize any possible champion induced handicap?

Comment: I suggest you to follow the stats on this site : [Legendsnet](http://www.legendsnet.com/globalstats/champions/all/0/6/03-24-2013/2) and sort by popularity to see wich champions are played and which ones aren't. You can have some filters to see what are doing the platiniums and what happens in Asia or Europe considering their are different playstyles for each region

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe it is possible to give a set list of champions that shouldn't be used in ranked as this will invariably be changed patch to patch. Many champions receive nerfs/buffs each and every patch as Riot tries to balance the game and many of those champions which tend to become overpowered are due to this process. There were and most likely still are champions within the game that for whatever reason have been nerfed to the point where most if not all of their match ups in lane will result in a loss. These are the champions that most people tend to shy away from and trolls are commonly found picking in ranked matches.

As an example, for a long time before Evelynn's rework, she was considered by many as a worthless champion, often inducing queue dodges by players that simply did not want one on their team. Now, after the rework, she is considered viable again and can quite easily become a dangerous force to be reckoned with if fed even remotely.

A simple rule of thumb which I try to follow (when I'm thinking coherently) is to play several *non-ranked* games with the champions I prefer playing after a recent patch, to figure out if they still feel as strong as they were prior to the patch. Items can quite easily change this as well as champion changes - they are modified in patches just as often to address the same kind of issues.
If they feel the same and I haven't noticed any specific champions that I would ordinarily have no problem against doing far better than they had previously, I will play ranked (if i feel like playing ranked, of course).

Again, as champions/items are balanced and reworked, the champions that were "overpowered" and "underpowered" will change over time, sometimes very drastically. In other words, any answer to this question will not be lasting, and is better suited to other sites.

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to what most people are saying here, and I'm ready to get downvoted, **Yes, There are champs that you should be avoiding during ranked.**  Some champions are just in a horrible spot at certain times, either due to itemization changes, jungle changes, champion balance changes, etc.

The people who are saying **no** here, probably do not follow the LCS or watch pro streams or higher Elo games.  The higher you rise in ELO, the smaller the champion pool will be.  If you watch an entire week of LCS, you'll notice about the same 20-25 champs are being picked EVERY GAME.  These are professionals, this is their job, they know the math behind the champions and their base stats and skills, this is why they make these picks.

Before blindly downvoting me and saying "All champions are viable", please do some research either on lolking or go youtube the last 20 LCS matches, and watch their picks.  (J4, Xin, Xerath, Nidalee, Rumble, Singed, Kayle, etc... In every game.)  There are some champs that are just in a good spot, and some are in a terrible spot, and have 0% pick rates in LCS.

Certain champs have 0% win/pick rate in LCS, and some have over 90% pick/ban rate in LCS.  That should be enough evidence for you to make in informed decision on this topic.

To answer your question, Champs that I personally think are in a bad spot right now (3/25/2013), also backed up by pro pick %s are here (keep in mind this can change with any new balancing/itemization changes):

> Veigar, Nami, Sion, Rengar, Gangplank, Urgot, Heimerdinger, Ziggs,
>   Trundle, Poppy, Fiora, Karma, Warwick, Galio, Viktor, Quinn, Zilean

Now, start downvoting me because your "main" appears on the list of baddies! ;)

Champions in a great spot right now (3/25/2013):

> Rumble, Twisted Fate, Taric, Amumu, Jarvan IV, Hecarim, Miss Fortune,
>   Elise, Nidalee, Xin Zhao, Shen, Garen, Vi, Cho'gath, Singed, Lee Sin,
>   Malphite, Draven, Ezreal, Kayle, Lux, Akali, Kha'Zix, Nasus, Volibear,
>   Thresh, Xerath

Comment: Keep in mind Rumble and Singed have huge Nerfs on PBE right now, so next week they may not be on this list anymore.

Comment: Hmm, I agree with most on the list. But lately i've been seeing Karma and Warwick popping up again at times. And they aren't to bad :p. I've been wondering about Sion tho, I think with the BotRK he might kick some ass top.

Comment: Karma is gaining popularity because of her visual upgrades/rework.  Warwick was in the Beta, so it makes sense that people still pick him.  However, there are alot of champs that do exactly what he does, but with more utility/teamfight presence.  *looks at Vi/Nocturne*

Comment: Completely disagree.  The Pro meta IS NOT AT ALL the ranked meta.  The Pro pace of play is much higher with much greater early game pressure.  The ranked meta, at any ELO, is slower and more drawn out.  This means that somebody like WW might be completely useless in a Pro game, but is entirely reasonable in ranked games.  WW can't handle the extreme early pressure in pro games, but if you relax that a little bit (as happens in ranked at any tier), he is actually reasonably strong due to his great mid game.  The same applies to champs like Veigar.

Comment: And to reephasize - don't base your champion picks solely on what pros pick.  Pros pick based on the pro meta.  You don't play in the Pro meta, so don't be too strongly influenced by picks for that meta.  I would say that there are a only a couple of champions that are non viable in ranked (Heimer maybe).

Comment: @KAI http://www.lolking.net/champions/ please read pick %, win %, etc.  I'm not going to argue with you, but there is a reason some champs have ~40% win rate and others have 55% win rate.  Olaf used to have 54% win rate, until after his recent nerf, he is under 40%, thus proving my point.  If you can't do the basic math, don't come here to flame my answers, especially when you don't provide one yourself.

Comment: I'm not flaming you.  I'm disagreeing.  I'm also about to point out that your arguments are inconsistent, and that the data you you point to does not support your arguments.  You first argued based on Pro picks.  You are now changing your argument to Lolking data, which does not track pro picks, but rather the normal/ranked meta.  That is, your data set speaks to my argument (picks should be based on the ranked meta, not what is popular in pro games) and not yours.

Comment: Furthermore, the basic math you are being insulting about does not support your argument.  For example, you list WW as in a bad spot, but Xerath is in a good spot.  Yet, your own data set shows that WW is more played and wins a higher percentage of games (and, for being in such a bad spot, WW is over 50% win rate).  Therefore, your own data set directly contradicts your hypothesis.  There are plenty of other examples of this - for example, Kha'Zix is one of the lowest win rate champions, but you list him as very strong.

Comment: **So, some champions win 40% of their games, and some win 55% of their games,  yet you say they are all equal and viable.** I'll end my part of the discussion with that comment.

Comment: A low win rate does not mean that a champion is not viable.  Vayne has been used successfully in number of pro games lately.  Yet she is only of the lowest win rate AD Carries.  Things like skill level are at least as large an effect as overall champion viability in things like Lolking stats.  Vayne is difficult to play, and therefore has low win rates due people not doing well with her in low skill games.  But she is completely viable if you know what you are doing with her (as shown in recent pro play).  Some champs are bad, but not very many are completely terrible.

Comment: Kayle and Nidalee are my favourites and I can say that I have 66/70 win ratio with them.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a set of heroes I shouldn't be using in ranked play?

**The only champions that you should play are the champions that you feel comfortable in playing against the champions the enemy team has selected.**

I think that is the most important bit of information for anyone considering to play LoL competitively. A lot of people fall into a trap of champion x is strong against champion y so they pick champion x but don't know how to play champion x or don't know how to play champion x against champion y. They then proceed to lose their lane and set their team back.

> is there any way to clarify what heroes are definitely under-classed somehow?

The only real way to say champion x is better than champion y is to look at their skills and stats and see if one does more damage, or one has better stats (armor, hp, attack, etc). Some champions *do* have some numbers problems, their abilities do too much damage compared to other similar abilities or they have too many stats. Some examples of this in the past season are Jax, Jayce and Urgot. Some popular high elo people have gone and created something called "tier" lists. You may have heard of Elementz's tier list for Summoners Rift or [Sauron's tier list for dominion](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2152948).

> Should I blindly follow these tier lists and just play the champions they say are the best and avoid/queue dodge if someone picks a champion they say are bad?

**NO!** And here is why.

Something I have found interesting is that different League of Legends regions have varying opinions on which champions are over powered and under powered (this changes patch to patch). Even different game modes have different opinions on which champions are stronger or weaker than others. As an example, there was a time when a lot of people in the North American region thought Mordekaiser was a bad champion where as the Brazil region thought he was very good.

What does this mean and why does this happen you may ask? Well the answer is: **There is more than one strategy (or meta as some people call it) and each champion fills a role differently.**

As an example, there was a time when a lot of people thought Urgot was a bad champion to play. And then at the IEM Hanover championship (Dignitas vs Moscow 5) Moscow 5 played Urgot bottom against Corki and Janna. Meanwhile, Moscow 5 had Alistar and Lee Sin Jungle/Counter Jungle/Roam. This was a strategy that had not really been seen before and the current "meta tier lists" didn't account for them. Another example would be sending two top instead of two bottom.

To sum it all up:

- Only play champions that you are comfortable playing.
- All champions can be effective as long as they are playing a role that suits them.

Comment: This is the best answer IMHO.  Riot strives to balance all champions and frequently adjusts their power levels.  Playing a champion you know well is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

With that many champions there will allways be balance issues, Riot does try to keep this to a minimum though. I don't think it's possible to give a list, because of 2 reasons. 1. There is simply too much subjective about it, it would lead to discussions and that is not what this site is for. 2. Because Riot tries to balance the game as much as possible, the answer given here would not be future proof at all (all could change within one week).

On a side note, if you have to ask what kind of champion might be better or worse than others, perhaps you should play a bit more normal. Get a bit more experience before trying ranked, You don't want to end up in bronze V if you can play a few normals first and learn more about the game and get placed in silver II as soon as you start ranked. (examples)

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of sites that show you who is "good" against certain champs such as http://smartp1ck.com/champions or http://www.lolcounter.com/champions, a lot of who to pick goes into knowing this information, what the enemy abilities are, and how to play against them.

Take time to learn your opponents strengths, and weaknesses.  Exploit the latter, be wary of the former, us sites like the above to learn how to counter champs or abilities, maybe they countered you first, well you can lane switch and/or build counter items.

A lot of who to play depends on where you are in the ladders, champs that stomp over the entire team in low ranked, can be pretty useless in higher ratings, because people know what they do and play to that characters weakness.

Finally it comes down to play style and what you're comfortable with, take time to learn to play defensively, learn to CS as best you can, and most of all *never* try a new char out for the first time in ranked, people will hate you for it, a few bot games, a few normals, goes a long way!